# Bitcoin sha256 to hex generates different result than expected

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sha256, bitcoin

I am trying to follow the instructions on deriving the WIF of a Hex bitcoin private key from - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format
However, when I try to hash the string (including 0x80 byte) I get different result than the expected.
I should have gotten 8147786C4D15106333BF278D71DADAF1079EF2D2440A4DDE37D747DED5403592.
Instead I receive e2e4146a36e9c455cf95a4f259f162c353cd419cc3fd0e69ae36d7d1b6cd2c09.

I read extensively on google and I understood that I should convert the string to binaries. I did, and then hashed the char array from those binaries to the same result.

Code is now working thanks to @Heinan Cabouly and @JaredPar

Here is the working code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

namespace Base58Encode
{

    internal class Program
    {
        public static string Str = "800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D";
        public static byte[] Bytes;
        public static void Main()
        {
            Bytes = StringToByteArray(Str);
            SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
            string hashstr = String.Empty;
            byte[] encrypt = sha.ComputeHash(Bytes);
            foreach (byte b in encrypt)
            {
                hashstr += b.ToString("x2");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(hashstr);
            //prints e2e4146a36e9c455cf95a4f259f162c353cd419cc3fd0e69ae36d7d1b6cd2c09
            //instead of 8147786C4D15106333BF278D71DADAF1079EF2D2440A4DDE37D747DED5403592
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```

This is how to hash a hex string SHA-256 in C#.
Thanks to all! Helped me out a lot!

Comment: `byte[] ba = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str);` - you do realize that's not parsing the string as hex, right? It's just converting the string to bytes using the ASCII encoding, so one byte per character. Search for "parse hex string to bytes c#" on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said here before me, the method you used for conversion isn't suitable. You can use this method (taken from stackoverflow by @JaredPar):

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                 .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                 .ToArray();
}
```

You call this function with your str (which represents the HEX string), and it will return the HEX representation.

From there, you can continue with your function as written.